# Parsing Tree of python classes and applying a grammar

Tags: python, class, recursion, tree, grammar

I'm trying to reduce a data file that is represented in a node-daughter structure. The data format is represented as the following:

( { [ GeoNode A, GeoNode B, GeoNode C ], GeoNode D }, { GeoNode E, GeoNode F }, GeoNode G )

Where GeoNode is a python object. I am trying to apply two operations in some scheme that will traverse the tree. The first will convert all GeoNodes in the current "level" into meshes. The second will merge the meshes together, at the end leaving me with a single mesh.

Here are what the steps in the above example would look like.

1. ( { [ Mesh A, Mesh B, Mesh C ], GeoNode D }, { GeoNode E, GeoNode F }, GeoNode G )
2. ( { Mesh ABC, GeoNode D }, { GeoNode E, GeoNode F }, GeoNode G )
3. ( { Mesh ABC, Mesh D }, { GeoNode E, GeoNode F }, GeoNode G )
4. ( Mesh ABCD, { GeoNode E, GeoNode F }, GeoNode G )
5. ( Mesh ABCD, { Mesh E, Mesh F }, GeoNode G )
6. ( Mesh ABCD, Mesh EF, GeoNode G )
7. ( Mesh ABCD, Mesh EF, Mesh G )
8. Mesh ABCDEFG

I currently represent the data structure as nested python lists containing GeoNodes. I'm able to traverse the tree in a depth-first fashion and print the structure. What is unclear to me is what to do when I have determined that I'm currently at [ Mesh A, Mesh B, Mesh C ]. I can easily make Mesh ABC, but then what? How can I ensure this gets matched with GeoNode D and propagated upward.

This is similar to trying to evaluate ( ( 1 + 1 ) + 2 + ( 3 + 5 ) ), but converting each int into to a float as well. However for my case I'm dealing with these classes, not floats and ints. Are there existing ways to do this in Python, or language independent examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must work bottom-up using a recursive transformation function.

```
def transform(s):
    ''' Receives a GeoNode structure as nested lists and returns a Mesh.
    '''
    if isinstance(s, list):
       return merge_meshes([transform(e) for e in s])
    else:
       assert isinstance(s, GeoNode)
       return geonode_to_mesh(s)
```

Comment: Late response, but this approach was useful and how I solved the problem.